# Print value as german thousand seperator along with decimal value using pySpark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I need to convert a dataframe column of String Type to double and add the format mask like thousand seperator and decimal place.

input dataframe:

```
column(StringType)
2655.00
15722.50
235354.66
```

required format:

```
(-1) * to_number(df.column, format mask)
```

Data is delivered as `.` as thousand separator and `,` as decimal separator and with 2 decimal numbers

Output column:

```
2.655,00
15.722,50
235.354,66
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# create a new colum with formatted date
df = df.withColumn('num_format', F.format_number('col', 2))

# switch the dot and comma
df = df.withColumn('num_format', F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace('num_format', '\\.', '@'), ',', '\\.'), '@', ','))
df.show()

+---------+----------+
|      col|num_format|
+---------+----------+
|   2655.0|  2.655,00|
|  15722.5| 15.722,50|
|235354.66|235.354,66|
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you...that's great :)

Answer (score 2):

Spark `date_format` returns string number formatted like `#,###,###.##` so you need to replace `.` by `,` and `.` by `,` to get the European format you want.

First, replace dots by `#` then commas by dots and finally replace `#` by a dot.

```
df.withColumn("european_format", regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
            format_number(col("column").cast("double"), 2), '\\.', '#'), ',', '\\.'), '#', ',')
          ).show()
```

Gives:

```
+---------+---------------+
|   column|european_format|
+---------+---------------+
|  2655.00|       2.655,00|
| 15722.50|      15.722,50|
|235354.66|     235.354,66|
+---------+---------------+
```